# remote server for selenium tests

Tags: node.js, selenium

### I want to use a static html page on a client machine as UI for starting selenium tests, which are then run on that same client machine, but are provided from a remote server.

**1.** I have set up a node.js server which delivers a static html page (acting as ui).

**2.** This page contains atm just buttons sending ajax requests with the respective filenames (*.js) back to the server.

**3.** The server starts those scripts as a childProcess.fork().

**4.** Unfortunally this means that those scripts run on that server machine.

**5.** I want them to run on the client machine.

---

**Question:**

Is there any way, framework, anything to met these requirements.

Comment: You can try with remote webdriver to drive the browser on the client from server machine.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried to follow your suggestions but the documentation on this is very sparse and partly confusing, especially concerning node.js.